# Will my kitten have medium or long hair?

Tags: cats, grooming

I just adopted this cutie. She is five or six weeks old. I am pretty sure she will not be short haired from the ear tufts, but I'm curious how long you think her hair will be? I have had medium haired cats but never a long haired cat and don't know how to tell the difference when they're kittens. Mainly I want to know how much brushing I should expect to be doing, lol.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your cat will be medium length hair.

You should get yourself a good brush and start to brush your cat on a weekly basis. This is mostly so your cat gets used to be brushed, as you will need to brush out knots in your cats fur from time to time.

Regular brushing is a good way to avoid hairballs before they become a problem.

This is the type of brush I use on my cat. She is shorthaired. [image]

All cats will at some point in their life need to be brushed, long haired cats need to be brushed weekly and old cats need to be brushed as a result of reduced mobility.

Comment: How can you tell she'll be medium length hair vs. long? I'll buy a brush like that :)